# How to get multiple vertically stacked divs to each cover a percentage of the parent divs height?

Tags: css, html, height

I have a wrapper div with 100% height which contained several divs, which include a header, a content and a footer div. I want these 3 divs to always cover the 100% height, while the header and footer have a static height. E.g. I want the content div to cover 100% - the height of footer + header. I can't seem to find a solution. Any ideas ?

Comment: Please provide your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Height in CSS can be funny.  Unless the parent container has a defined height then percentages won't do anything.  Fortunately this is often easy to work around.  For most cases if you set html, body, and your wrapper to `height: 100%;` (along with everything else your wrapper may be nested in) then you can use the `calc()` function from CSS3.  [Support](http://caniuse.com/#feat=calc) for `calc()` is (mostly) pretty decent.

Here's a quick [example](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/eNeypm).

The main magic happens in the .content css rule:

```
.content {
  height: calc(100% - 50px - 50px); // 100% - height of header - height of footer
}
```

This is remarkably close to what's called a sticky footer [(example)](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/yNPpOm).  The only difference is that instead of `height: 100%` you would use `min-height: 100%` for html, body, and .wrapper.  This makes it so that the footer will always remain at the bottom of the page (rather than the screen).  If there is not enough content to push it to the bottom, it still sits there.  Whereas if there is more content than will fit on the screen then it simply keeps getting pushed down until there is no content left.  It's one of my favorite CSS code bits.

Answer (score 0):

If you use absolute positioning on the content section you can have it always take up the full space between the header and footer:

```
#content{ 
    width: 100%; 
    background-color: yellow; 
    position: absolute; 
    top: 100px; 
    bottom: 100px; 
}
```

Then you can use `height: 33.33333%` to make each div inside the content take up roughly 1/3 of the height (there may be a pixel line at the end as 1/3 does not convert into percentages nicely).

You can see the full fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/1b1o9uop/)